# Detecting all lines in line-based structure using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, hough-transform, houghlines

I've been trying to detect all lines in a line-based structure and I've been falling short. I've learned about the HoughLinesP function, however it doesn't seem to work good enough for more complex images. I've been playing with the parameters and it either doesn't detect all the lines, or detects all the lines but splits them into many very small lines that are hard to connect. I've been trying to implement a function that'd join all the consecutive lines into one but with many edge cases and small problems it doesn't work very well either. I've been wondering, is there maybe a better way to approach this problem? Or maybe since this seems like a very simple problem there exists some kind of solution that I haven't found?
Base image:
[image]
Detection with high threshold (longer lines, some lines not detected):
[image]
Detection with low threshold (shorter lines but all of the lines detected):
[image]

Comment: you should question your approach. how was the fractal fern made? why do you not use the source data, why do you have to work with the fern's *drawing*?

Comment: The whole point of this project is to try and do it the other way around and detect the lines from the image. I have the source data of this particular fern, but I'm trying to figure out a way to do this when I encounter an image that wasn't created by me.

Comment: I think Hough is pointless here. it's made for noisy data and the results can appear stochastic. you have a pixel-perfect drawing... but it also *self-intersects*, so good luck recovering the true tree structure from that. if it didn't do that, I'd still recommend walking the pixels neighbor by neighbor, recording direction for each step, recording forks where they happen, and then simplifying obvious lines by merging adjacent lines that have the same slope (unless they meet in a fork).

Comment: I like that idea and would like to add something: You could assign a confidence value for every segment from a fork away. Very high confidence that it belongs to the path that entered a fork, lower confidence for higher forked angles. This way you can start at the single beginning and perform a depth-search from there to reach every "leaf". In the end make sure that every segment only belongs to one path by only keeping highest confidence pathes.